# How to Set Up Debugging with Dockerized SAM Local

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker-compose, aws-lambda, dockerfile, aws-sam-cli

I'm working on a project using AWS Lambda with Node.js. We use Docker containers for our development environment.

Our current setup spins up AWS SAM local on port :3000. It runs start-api and mounts the functions in my template.yml file. I test these functions using postman to send JSON to the mounted API endpoint like so: http://127.0.0.1:3000/foo

The Docker setup also spins up a separate Node.js instance on :4000.

I'm able to test the Lambda stuff locally as described above. However, I want to activate debugging so that I can step through the function and inspect variables as opposed to using `console.log()`. I can't figure out how to edit the Dockerfile / docker-compose.yml to make that happen.

Here is my docker-compose file:

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    build: ./web
    container_name: someapp
    command: npm run dev
    volumes:
      - ./web:/usr/app/
      - /usr/app/node_modules
    ports:
      - "4000:4000"
    environment:
      DATABASE_URL: mongo://someapp:someapp@10.10.62.205:37017,10.10.62.205:37018,10.10.62.205:37019/somedb
  sam:
    build: serverless/.
    container_name: samlocal
    command: sam local start-api --host 0.0.0.0
    environment:
      COMPOSE_CONVERT_WINDOWS_PATHS: 1
      SAM_DOCKER_VOLUME_BASEDIR: ${CURRENT_DIRECTORY}/serverless
      DATABASE_URL: mongo://someapp:someapp@10.10.62.205:37017,10.10.62.205:37018,10.10.62.205:37019/somedb
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - ./serverless:/var/opt
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
```

Here is the Dockerfile for SAM, which is in a directory called "serverless":

```
FROM alpine:3.6

ENV VERSION=0.2.2

RUN apk add --no-cache curl && \
    curl -sSLO https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sam-local/releases/download/v${VERSION}/sam_${VERSION}_linux_386.tar.gz && \
    tar -C /usr/local/bin -zxvf /sam_${VERSION}_linux_386.tar.gz && \
    apk del curl && \
    rm -f /sam_${VERSION}_linux_386.tar.gz

# awscli for "sam package" and "sam deploy"
RUN apk add --no-cache py-pip && pip install awscli

WORKDIR /var/opt

EXPOSE 3000
```

I've tried various permutations of adding the --d flag to the "sam" service in RUN directive in docker-compose.yml. For example: `sam local start-api --host 0.0.0.0 --d 8080`. And then I try to change the port mapping to expose it. However, I can't figure out how to get the port mapping to work. As soon as I hit the endpoint I get port errors.

I'm still getting up to speed on docker / docker-compose and a total nube when it comes to the Lambda stuff, so sorry if the question is silly.

TIA!

Answer (score 5):

I have determined that my initial approach was incorrect.

The benefit of making SAM Local part of my docker-compose setup --or so I thought-- was that I was saving my teammates the trouble of installing it locally on their machines. And starting it in this way:

`sam local start-api --host 0.0.0.0`

seemed to confer the additional convenience of "automagically" mounting all of the API endpoints.

However, this does not afford the user the flexibility to toggle debugging on and off. Nor does it allow the user to switch between POST-ing input with Postman or loading the input data from a file.

So here is the way I'm doing it now:

```
$ npm install aws-sam-local --g
$ cd path/to/my/template.yml
```

To use Postman:

```
$ sam local start-api
```

or Postman plus debugger:

```
$sam local start-api -d 5858
```

To bypass Postman and simply read the input from a file:

```
$ sam local invoke "NameOfResource" -e ./path/to/file.json
```

or to do the same with a debugger:

```
$ sam local invoke "NameOfResource" -e ./path/to/file.json -d 5858
```

NOTE: in the above example, `"NameOfResource"` must be a string and it must match the resource name listed in template.yml (in case it is different from the actual function name in the source code).

Doing it this way I am able to connect a remote Node.js debugger in WebStorm and set breakpoints. I'm also able to connect a Visual Studio Code debugger. However, Visual Studio Code seems to ignore my breakpoints, forcing me to use `debugger;` statements. This is unfortunate since my teammates all use Visual Studio Code and WebStorm is not free. If anyone knows how to get around the Visual Studio issue, holler!

Comment: Having the same initial issue as you. Where did you end up finding that the initial approach is incorrect? We are doing something similar and facing the same issues.

Comment: Hi Jako. SAM Local is a CLI tool, but I was basically attempting to use it as a runtime in order to avoid developers having to install it and start it manually. My workflow requirements include the ability to easily switch between sending network requests and JSON files as input to my local Lambda functions. I also need to be able to easily switch between the normal mode of operation and debug mode. SAM Local provides all of those options, but you need to run different commands to invoke them. Simply starting the API in a docker image will not allow you to invoke the different options.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an article explaining the operation of the PyDev remote debugger for stepping through Lambda code running in a Docker container through the Eclipse IDE.

https://medium.com/debugging-aws-lambda-functions-from-eclipse-with/debugging-aws-lambda-python-function-with-eclipse-using-pydev-1e0fa4b2deff

It is Python instead of Node but it may help to get a general understanding of debugging scripts running inside Docker containers.

Comment: Hi @Nick. This answer should be a comment, as you're providing a link only. I invite you to edit your answer to improve it. Please take a look at [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).